# JAX-RS Post multiple objects

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs

I have a method;

```
@POST
@Path("test")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public void test(ObjectOne objectOne, ObjectTwo objectTwo)
```

Now I know I can post a single object in json format, just putting it into the body.
But is it possible to do multiple objects? If so, how?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

The answer is **no**.

The reason is simple: This about the parameters you can receive in a method. They must be related to the request. Right? So they must be either headers or cookies or query parameters or matrix parameters or path parameters or **request body**. (Just to tell the complete story there is additional types of parameters called context).

Now, when you receive JSON object in your request, you receive it in a  **request body**. How many bodies the request may have? One and only one. So you can receive only one JSON object.

Comment: @Scholle I wonder how did you decide that my answer is about subsequent requests?

Comment: Mmmm a List<SomeEntity> has **multiple** objects, no?

Comment: @StijndeWitt Array can contain multiple objects. This is the purpose of array, right? JAX-RS API cannot receive multiple objects. So as tine2k states in his answer: you can have container object that will contain multiple objects.

Comment: The answer "no" is FALSE. "How many bodies the request may have?" In a "multipart/form-data", there can be more bodies.

Answer (score 85):

You **can not** use your method like this as correctly stated by Tarlog.

However, you can do this:

```
@POST
@Path("test")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public void test(List<ObjectOne> objects)
```

or this:

```
@POST
@Path("test")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public void test(BeanWithObjectOneAndObjectTwo containerObject)
```

Furthermore, you can always combine your method with GET parameters:

```
@POST
@Path("test")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public void test(List<ObjectOne> objects, @QueryParam("objectTwoId") long objectTwoId)
```

Comment: Last one (with QueryParam) ain't working. Error -  "The server refused this request because the request entity is in a format not supported by the requested resource for the requested method (Unsupported Media Type)"

Comment: @tine2k for me `List<Object> objects is not working` here I post my problem [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49323401/sending-post-axios-request-with-array-of-objects)

Comment: To Java newcomers : don’t google `ObjectOne`, it’s not a special object class but a dummy name you have to replace by your own class name.

Answer (score 39):

If we look at what the OP is trying to do, he/she is trying to post two (possibly unrelated) JSON objects. First any solution to try and send one part as the body, and one part as some other param, IMO,  are *horrible* solutions. POST data should go in the body. It's not right to do something just because it works. Some work-arounds might be violating basic REST principles.

I see a few solutions

1. Use application/x-www-form-urlencoded
2. Use Multipart
3. Just wrap them in a single parent object

### 1. Use application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Another option is to just use `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. We can actually have JSON values. For examle

```
curl -v http://localhost:8080/api/model \
     -d 'one={"modelOne":"helloone"}' \
     -d 'two={"modelTwo":"hellotwo"}'

public class ModelOne {
    public String modelOne;
}

public class ModelTwo {
    public String modelTwo;
}

@Path("model")
public class ModelResource {

    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
    public String post(@FormParam("one") ModelOne modelOne,
                       @FormParam("two") ModelTwo modelTwo) {
        return modelOne.modelOne + ":" + modelTwo.modelTwo;
    }
}
```

The one thing we need to get this to work is a `ParamConverterProvider` to get this to work. Below is one that has been implemented by Michal Gadjos of the Jersey Team (found [here with explanation](http://blog.dejavu.sk/2014/02/11/inject-custom-java-types-via-jax-rs-parameter-annotations/)).

```
@Provider
public class JacksonJsonParamConverterProvider implements ParamConverterProvider {

    @Context
    private Providers providers;

    @Override
    public <T> ParamConverter<T> getConverter(final Class<T> rawType,
                                              final Type genericType,
                                              final Annotation[] annotations) {
        // Check whether we can convert the given type with Jackson.
        final MessageBodyReader<T> mbr = providers.getMessageBodyReader(rawType,
                genericType, annotations, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE);
        if (mbr == null
              || !mbr.isReadable(rawType, genericType, annotations, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE)) {
            return null;
        }

        // Obtain custom ObjectMapper for special handling.
        final ContextResolver<ObjectMapper> contextResolver = providers
                .getContextResolver(ObjectMapper.class, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE);

        final ObjectMapper mapper = contextResolver != null ?
                contextResolver.getContext(rawType) : new ObjectMapper();

        // Create ParamConverter.
        return new ParamConverter<T>() {

            @Override
            public T fromString(final String value) {
                try {
                    return mapper.reader(rawType).readValue(value);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    throw new ProcessingException(e);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public String toString(final T value) {
                try {
                    return mapper.writer().writeValueAsString(value);
                } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
                    throw new ProcessingException(e);
                }
            }
        };
    }
}
```

If you aren't scanning for resource and providers, just register this provider, and the above example should work.

### 2. Use Multipart

One solution that no one has mentioned, is to use [multipart](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.2). This allows us to send arbitrary parts in a request. Since each request can only have one entity body, multipart is the work around, as it allows to have different parts (with their own content types) as part of the entity body.

Here is an example using Jersey (see official doc [here](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/media.html#multipart))

Dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>
    <version>${jersey-2.x.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Register the `MultipartFeature`

```
import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.MultiPartFeature;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;

@ApplicationPath("/api")
public class JerseyApplication extends ResourceConfig {

    public JerseyApplication() {
        packages("stackoverflow.jersey");
        register(MultiPartFeature.class);
    }
}
```

Resource class

```
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.FormDataParam;

@Path("foobar")
public class MultipartResource {

    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    public Response postFooBar(@FormDataParam("foo") Foo foo,
                               @FormDataParam("bar") Bar bar) {
        String response = foo.foo + "; " + bar.bar;
        return Response.ok(response).build();
    }

    public static class Foo {
        public String foo;
    }

    public static class Bar {
        public String bar;
    }
}
```

Now the tricky part with some clients is that there isn't a way to set the `Content-Type` of each body part, which is required for the above to work. The multipart provider will look up message body reader, based on the type of each part. If it's not set to `application/json` or a type, the `Foo` or `Bar` has a reader for, this will fail. We will use JSON here. There's no extra configuration but to have a reader available. I'll use Jackson. With the below dependency, no other configuration should be required, as the provider will be discovered through classpath scanning.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
    <version>${jersey-2.x.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Now the test. I will be using [**cURL**](http://curl.haxx.se/). You can see I explicitly set the `Content-Type` for each part with `type`. The `-F` signifies to different part. (See very bottom of the post for an idea of how the request body actually looks.)

> `curl -v -X POST \
>           -H "Content-Type:multipart/form-data" \ 
>           -F "bar={\"bar\":\"BarBar\"};type=application/json" \
>           -F "foo={\"foo\":\"FooFoo\"};type=application/json" \
>           http://localhost:8080/api/foobar`
>   **Result:** `FooFoo; BarBar`

The result is exactly as we expected. If you look at the resource method, all we do is return this string `foo.foo + "; " + bar.bar`, gathered from the two JSON objects.

You can see some examples using some different JAX-RS clients, in the links below. You will also see some server side example also from those different JAX-RS implementations. Each link should have somewhere in it a link to the official documentation for that implementation

- [Jersey example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27614403/2587435)
- [Resteasy example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27623162/2587435)
- [CXF example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28483262/2587435)

There are other JAX-RS implementations out there, but you will need to find the documentation for it yourself. The above three are the only ones I have experience with.

As far as Javascript clients, most of the example I see (e.g. [some of these](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5392344/2587435) involve setting the `Content-Type` to undefined/false (using `FormData`), letting the Browser handle the it. But this will not work for us, as the Browser will not set the `Content-Type` for each part. And the default type is `text/plain`.

I'm sure there are libraries out there that allow setting the type for each part, but just to show you how it can be done manually, I'll post an example (got a little help from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5935286/2587435). I'll be using Angular, but the grunt work of building the entity body will be plain old Javascript.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="multipartApp">
    <head>
        <script src="js/libs/angular.js/angular.js"></script>
        <script>
            angular.module("multipartApp", [])
            .controller("defaultCtrl", function($scope, $http) {

                $scope.sendData = function() {
                    var foo = JSON.stringify({foo: "FooFoo"});
                    var bar = JSON.stringify({bar: "BarBar"});

                    var boundary = Math.random().toString().substr(2);                    
                    var header = "multipart/form-data; charset=utf-8; boundary=" + boundary;

                    $http({
                        url: "/api/foobar",
                        headers: { "Content-Type": header }, 
                        data: createRequest(foo, bar, boundary),
                        method: "POST"
                    }).then(function(response) {
                        $scope.result = response.data;
                    });
                };

                function createRequest(foo, bar, boundary) {
                    var multipart = "";
                    multipart += "--" + boundary
                        + "\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=foo"
                        + "\r\nContent-type: application/json"
                        + "\r\n\r\n" + foo + "\r\n";        
                    multipart += "--" + boundary
                        + "\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=bar"
                        + "\r\nContent-type: application/json"
                        + "\r\n\r\n" + bar + "\r\n";
                    multipart += "--" + boundary + "--\r\n";
                    return multipart;
                }
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div ng-controller="defaultCtrl">
            <button ng-click="sendData()">Send</button>
            <p>{{result}}</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The interesting part is the `createRequest` function. This is where we build the multipart, setting the `Content-Type` of each part to `application/json`, and concatenating the stringified `foo` and `bar` objects to each part. If you are unfamiliar multipart format [see here for more info](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.2). The other interesting part is the header. We set it to `multipart/form-data`.

Below is the result. In Angular I just used the result to show in the HTML, with `$scope.result = response.data`. The button you see was just to make the request. You will also see the request data in [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/)

[image]

### 3. Just wrap them in a single parent object

This option should be self explanatory, as others have already mentioned.

Answer (score 8):

The next approach is usually applied in this kind of cases:

```java
TransferObject {
    ObjectOne objectOne;
    ObjectTwo objectTwo;

    //getters/setters
}

@POST
@Path("test")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public void test(TransferObject object){
//        object.getObejctOne()....
}
```

Comment: This answer is great, however the question was JAX-RS, and the multipart-solution provided is in Jersey. It took me some time to convert it to JAX-RS, that seams to be even more simple.

Answer (score 4):

You can't put two separate objects in one single POST call as explained by Tarlog.

Anyway you could create a third container object that contains the first two objects and pass that one within the POS call.

Answer (score 2):

I have also faced with these problem. Maybe this will help.

```
@POST
@Path("/{par}")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Object centralService(@PathParam("par") String operation, Object requestEntity) throws JSONException {

    ObjectMapper objectMapper=new ObjectMapper();

    Cars cars = new Cars();  
    Seller seller = new Seller();
    String someThingElse;

    HashMap<String, Object> mapper = new HashMap<>(); //Diamond )))

    mapper = (HashMap<String, Object>) requestEntity;

    cars=objectMapper.convertValue(mapper.get("cars"), Cars.class);
    seller=objectMapper.convertValue(mapper.get("seller"), Seller.class);
    someThingElse=objectMapper.convertValue(mapper.get("someThingElse"), String.class);

    System.out.println("Cars Data "+cars.toString());

    System.out.println("Sellers Data "+seller.toString());

    System.out.println("SomeThingElse "+someThingElse);

    if (operation.equals("search")) {
        System.out.println("Searching");
    } else if (operation.equals("insertNewData")) {
        System.out.println("Inserting New Data");
    } else if (operation.equals("buyCar")) {
        System.out.println("Buying new Car");
    }

    JSONObject json=new JSONObject();
    json.put("result","Works Fine!!!");


    return json.toString();

}


*******CARS POJO********@XmlRootElement for Mapping Object to XML or JSON***

@XmlRootElement
public class Cars {
    private int id;
    private String brand;
    private String model;
    private String body_type;
    private String fuel;
    private String engine_volume;
    private String horsepower;
    private String transmission;
    private String drive;
    private String status;
    private String mileage;
    private String price;
    private String description;
    private String picture;
    private String fk_seller_oid;
    } // Setters and Getters Omitted 

*******SELLER POJO********@XmlRootElement for Mapping Object to XML or JSON***

@XmlRootElement
public class Seller {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String surname;
    private String phone;
    private String email;
    private String country;
    private String city;
    private String paste_date;
    }//Setters and Getters omitted too


*********************FRONT END Looks Like This******************

$(function(){
$('#post').on('click',function(){
        console.log('Begins');
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url: '/ENGINE/cars/test',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            data:complexObject(),
            success: function(data){
                console.log('Sended and returned'+JSON.stringify(data));
            },
            error: function(err){
                console.log('Error');
                console.log("AJAX error in request: " + JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
            }
        }); //-- END of Ajax
        console.log('Ends POST');
        console.log(formToJSON());

    }); // -- END of click function   POST


function complexObject(){
    return JSON.stringify({
                "cars":{"id":"1234","brand":"Mercedes","model":"S class","body_type":"Sedan","fuel":"Benzoline","engine_volume":"6.5",
                "horsepower":"1600","transmission":"Automat","drive":"Full PLag","status":"new","mileage":"7.00","price":"15000",
                "description":"new car and very nice car","picture":"mercedes.jpg","fk_seller_oid":"1234444"},
        "seller":{  "id":"234","name":"Djonotan","surname":"Klinton","phone":"+994707702747","email":"email@gmail.com",                 "country":"Azeribaijan","city":"Baku","paste_date":"20150327"},
        "someThingElse":"String type of element"        
    }); 
} //-- END of Complex Object
});// -- END of JQuery -  Ajax
```

Answer (score 1):

It can be done by having the POST method declared to accept array of objects. Example like this

```
T[] create(@RequestBody T[] objects) {
for( T object : objects ) {
   service.create(object);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
to @Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED})
Then you can putting multiple objects into the body

Answer (score 0):

My solution is written for CXF, it appears to be quite simple.

```
import org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.ext.multipart.Multipart;

@POST
@Path("paramTest")
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
public GenericResult paramTest(
    @Multipart(value = "myData", type=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        ObjectOne myData,
    @Multipart(value = "infoList", type=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        ObjectTwo[] infoList);
```

The test code for this with io.restassurred:

```
@Test
public void paramTest()
{
    String payload1 = "" +
        "{ \"name\": \"someName\", \"branch\": \"testBranch\" }";
    String payload2 =
        " [ { \"name\": \"cn\", \"status\": \"ts\" }," +
            "{ \"name\": \"cn2\", \"status\": \"ts2\" } ] ]";
    RestAssured.
    given().
    contentType("multipart/form-data").
        multiPart("myData", payload1, "application/json").
        multiPart("infoList", payload2, "application/json").
    post(String.format("%s/paramTest", API_PATH)).
    then().
    statusCode(HttpStatus.SC_OK).
    contentType(ContentType.JSON).
    body("success", Matchers.equalTo(true));
}
```