# How to send multipart/form-data form content by ajax (no jquery)?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am trying to send some form without reloading the page and I am trying to understand the under-the-hood details therefore not using any JavaScript library:

```
var http = createRequestObject();
function createRequestObject() {
    var objAjax;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        objAjax=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {// code for IE6, IE5
        objAjax=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    return objAjax;
}

function display_progress() { ... }    

function upload_file() {
    var request = 'UploaderServlet';
    http.open('post', request);
    http.onreadystatechange = display_progress;
    http.send(null); // HERE PROBABLY THE DATA SHOULD BE SENT
}

<form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="upload_form" name="upload_form" method="POST" action="UploaderServlet" onsubmit="upload_file(); return false;" target="upload_target">
Choose a file <br />  
<input name="file" size="27" type="file" id="file" /> <br/> 
<input type="submit" name="uploadSubmitButton" value="Upload" /><br /> 
<br />  
</form> 

<iframe id="upload_target" name="upload_target" src="#" style="width:0;height:0;border:0px solid #fff;"></iframe>
```

The upload_file() is called, but if I get it right, the data is not sent. Please advice regarding the correct way to send the data.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Pass attribute in form `{url:"",method:"",data:{...},callback:function(){}}`

```
var ajax=function(){
  try{
    var xml       =new XMLHttpRequest();
    var args      =arguments;
    var context   =this;
    var multipart ="";

    xml.open(args[0].method,args[0].url,true);

    if(args[0].method.search(/post/i)!=-1){
      var boundary=Math.random().toString().substr(2);
      xml.setRequestHeader("content-type",
                  "multipart/form-data; charset=utf-8; boundary=" + boundary);
      for(var key in args[0].data){
        multipart += "--" + boundary
                   + "\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=" + key
                   + "\r\nContent-type: application/octet-stream"
                   + "\r\n\r\n" + args[0].data[key] + "\r\n";
      }
      multipart += "--"+boundary+"--\r\n";
    }

    xml.onreadystatechange=function(){
      try{
        if(xml.readyState==4){
          context.txt=xml.responseText;
          context.xml=xml.responseXML;
          args[0].callback();
        }
      }
      catch(e){}
    }

    xml.send(multipart);
  }
  catch(e){}
}
```

If you want to get back response you can use this

```
var response={};
ajax.call(response,{...args...})
```

and you can retrieve all data by `response.txt` or `response.xml`

**A bit late update**

As for @Varun question about `<input type='file'>` uploads, this code can't handle file uploads directly, in order to send files using this code, you need to perform preprocessing of the raw file data using [File API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File) to get non-binary streams (like base64 or any other bin2hex-like form).

But, since it's a 2015 year, I can suggest to move from the construction of the multipart streams to something a bit more robust, like the [FormData API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/FormData).

Comment: cannot understand what will we provide in data for `<input type=file`

Answer (score 1):

Your `XMLHttpRequest` code looks fine other than the `null` you're passing into `send`. You need to pass in a string containing the data to send (properly encoded, of course).

Note that if you want to send the file referenced by your `input[type=file]` field, you'll need to read it into memory, and the only way to do that is to use the new [File API](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/), which isn't broadly-supported yet.

If you're trying to send a file with a progress bar, you could do that by posting blocks of it you've read via the File API on a browser that supports the File API, perhaps fall back to a Flash-based uploader like [swfupload](http://swfupload.org/) if the browser doesn't support the File API, and fall back to a normal form submission if the browser doesn't support Flash.

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer. http://www.johnboy.com/scripts/php-upload-progress-meter/progress.phps - here somehow the YUI manages to send the form data successfully without File API / flash etc.

Comment: @BreakPhreak: Ah, yes, that's the other way, which requires server-side support: You do a standard form post, then (separately) poll the server asking how much data it's received so far, and show a progress indicator that way. But of course, that requires server-side support. (It also requires that the browser let you do an ajax call alongside a running form POST, but most will.) Still cool, though, if you're in control of both sides of the transaction.

Comment: first, I do provide a server-side support for a progress bar. still I can't get how the data is sent. I mean, I've looked into the YUI source (http://yui.yahooapis.com/2.9.0/build/connection/connection_core-min.js", _setForm function) and that's looks like a nightmare :)

Comment: @BreakPhreak: They're submitting a form in an iframe, see the `uploadFile` function in https://github.com/yui/yui2/blob/master/src/connection/js/connectionx.js.

Answer (score 1):

need to pass in a string containing the data to send (properly encoded, of course).

w File API, whicYour XMLHtth isn't broadly-supported yet.

If you're trying le API on a browser that supports the File API, perhaps fall back to a Flash-based uploader likpRequest code looks fine other than the null you're passing into send.e swfupload if the browser doesn't support the File API, and fall back to a normal form submission if the browser doesn't supporto send a file with a progress bar, you could do that by posting blocks ofYou  it you've read via the Fit Flash.