# Ajax upload file error with Google Chrome?

Tags: php, javascript

I'm using noswfupload (ajax uploader) with my web application, and it work fine with Firefox and IE, but it's not working with Google Chrome. I found an error which show that "PHP Warning:  Missing boundary in multipart/form-data POST data in Unknown on line 0"

could anyone tell me how to solve this problem?

Comment: Looks like the library has a bug where it's not formatting the request correctly. Is there a bug tracker with that library?

Comment: nop !! i found an error in error log file.

Comment: If it doesn't work in Google Chrome, then it probably doesn't work for Safari as well. Is there a reason why you're using this framework instead of using the [FormData](http://hacks.mozilla.org/2010/05/formdata-interface-coming-to-firefox/) object?

Comment: I can customize it and integrate with my web application easily with its event and object, also no require any other framework such as jQuery or mootools. I'm trying to fix it :)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about your specific uploader, but:

This error is a problem with the way that your xhr request headers are set, and also your request data. Valid syntax ( from my chrome debug console ) looks like this:

request header:

```
Content-Type:multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundarykEVXyg09HZBMzplL
```

request data:

```
------WebKitFormBoundarykEVXyg09HZBMzplL
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="foo_bar"

data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJ
     [....]
pAkhCD/9k=
------WebKitFormBoundarykEVXyg09HZBMzplL--
```

You can see the http rfc here: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/7_2_Multipart.html , it mentions the boundary syntax in the header....

You can manually change the header as in this answer: [How to send multipart/form-data form content by ajax (no jquery)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5933949/how-to-send-multipart-form-data-form-content-by-ajax-no-jquery) , or you can try to solve it at a higher level.

The formData object can mimic those parameters too, (although it's not implemented in all browsers) ... https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/XMLHttpRequest/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects

I had a problem with a jquery ajax call to a php file (with the same error) and solved it by ditching jquery and using formData and the raw httpxhrrequest.