# When to use setRequestHeader for Ajax and XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, ajax, http-headers

1. Should I ever manually set `setRequestHeader` to 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' for ajax POST?
2. Should I ever manually set `setRequestHeader` to 'multipart/form-data' for ajax file upload?
3. Are there different requirements for XMLHttpRequest and XMLHttpRequest2 regarding `setRequestHeader`?

Common programming sense is telling me that browser can easily decide what headers should be sent depending on values from .open() and .send() methods. And that `setRequestHeader` should be used only if I have some custom headers to send. But is this really the case here?

I am looking for "what's really going on under the hood" type of answer!

.

```
xhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'multipart/form-data');  // for files

xhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded'); // for POST escaped 'form' data
```

### edit:

I could similarly ask for Connection or Content-length headers. Many tutorials recommend sending those headers. But in practice this is wrong. Browsers are considering those headers as `unsafe` and send internally calculated values.

```
http.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
http.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
```

### edit2:

Like in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12348216/uploading-a-file-with-xmlhttprequest-missing-boundary-in-multipart-form-data) everything started to work when I removed content-type and other nonsensical headers.
Now I really want to know what is under the hood of `setRequestHeader` and when should I really use it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Should I ever manually set setRequestHeader to 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' for ajax POST?

Yes. If you pass `send()` a string (which you would be for application/x-www-form-urlencoded) then the default content-type is text/plain.

> Should I ever manually set setRequestHeader to 'multipart/form-data' for ajax file upload?

No. If you are using multipart/form-data for a file upload then you will be using a FormData object and XHR will set it for you.

If you set it to just `multipart/form-data` then you'll omit the boundary information and it won't work.

> Are there different requirements for XMLHttpRequest and XMLHttpRequest2

Work on XHR 2 has been discontinued.

Comment: Surprisingly good answer :) Could you explain in little more detail `Work on XHR 2 has been discontinued`.

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest2/ says "Work on this document has been discontinued and it should not be referenced or used as a basis for implementation."