# AWS lambda function to upload file

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, lambda

I am trying to upload a file using APIGateway and Lambda (Go). Idea is to upload the file and then move that file to S3 bucket. But for some reason I keep getting an error. Here is my code.

```
func parse(request events.APIGatewayProxyRequest) {
    var fileBytes []byte
    var filename, contentType string
    contentType, params, parseErr := mime.ParseMediaType(request.Headers["Content-Type"])
    fmt.Printf("DEBUG:: contentType: %v\n", contentType)
    if parseErr != nil || !strings.HasPrefix(contentType, "multipart/") {
        logger.Instance.Error("unexpected error when retrieving a part of the message", zap.Error(parseErr))
        return
    }
    fmt.Printf("DEBUG:: request body: %v\n", request.Body)
    multipartReader := multipart.NewReader(strings.NewReader(request.Body), params["boundary"])
    // defer request.Body.Close()
    for {
        part, err := multipartReader.NextPart()
        if err == io.EOF {
            break
        }
        if err != nil {
            logger.Instance.Error("unexpected error when retrieving a part of the message", zap.Error(err))
            return
        }
        defer part.Close()

        fileBytes, err = ioutil.ReadAll(part)
        if err != nil {
            logger.Instance.Error("failed to read content of the part", zap.Error(err))
            return
        }
    }
    logger.Instance.Info("handler.parseForm", zap.String("ParseForm", filename))
    logger.Instance.Info("handler.parseForm", zap.String("ParseForm", contentType))
    logger.Instance.Info("handler.parseForm", zap.Int("ParseForm", len(fileBytes)))
}
```

I get the following Error:

```
{
    "level": "error",
    "ts": 1614221323.4001436,
    "caller": "uploadsvc/uploadsvc.go:53",
    "msg": "unexpected error when retrieving a part of the message",
    **"error": "multipart: NextPart: bufio: buffer full",**
    "stacktrace": "main.parse\n\t/home/sarvs/go-workspace/src/uploadsvc/uploadsvc.go:53\nmain.handler\n\t/home/sarvs/go-workspace/src/uploadsvc/uploadsvc.go:144\nreflect.Value.call\n\t/snap/go/7013/src/reflect/value.go:476\nreflect.Value.Call\n\t/snap/go/7013/src/reflect/value.go:337\ngithub.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/lambda.NewHandler.func1\n\t/home/sarvs/go/pkg/mod/github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go@v1.22.0/lambda/handler.go:124\ngithub.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/lambda.lambdaHandler.Invoke\n\t/home/sarvs/go/pkg/mod/github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go@v1.22.0/lambda/handler.go:24\ngithub.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/lambda.(*Function).Invoke\n\t/home/sarvs/go/pkg/mod/github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go@v1.22.0/lambda/function.go:64\nreflect.Value.call\n\t/snap/go/7013/src/reflect/value.go:476\nreflect.Value.Call\n\t/snap/go/7013/src/reflect/value.go:337\nnet/rpc.(*service).call\n\t/snap/go/7013/src/net/rpc/server.go:377"
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25493706/ajax-upload-file-to-golang-server-with-content-type-multipart it might be the issue with the way you are calling the API from code...

Comment: I am using postman to upload the file. I select form-data then select the file. I name the key as file. Am I missing anything?

Comment: Do you see `DEBUG:: contentType: ....` message being logged?