# RestEasy: Is it possible to post two complexe objects?

Tags: forms, post, resteasy

I am trying to transport two complexe objects as parameter with RestEasy with @POST annotation.

```java
@POST
@Path("/save")
@Consumes("application/json")
public void save(ComplexeObjectAleph objectAleph, ComplexeObjectBeth objectBeth);
```

With only one parameter is allright, but with two - I get Exception:

```java
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: No content to map to Object due to end of input
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper._initForReading(ObjectMapper.java:2775)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper._readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2691)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:1315)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJsonProvider.readFrom(JacksonJsonProvider.java:419)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.MessageBodyReaderContextImpl.proceed(MessageBodyReaderContextImpl.java:105)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.interceptors.encoding.GZIPDecodingInterceptor.read(GZIPDecodingInterceptor.java:63)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.MessageBodyReaderContextImpl.proceed(MessageBodyReaderContextImpl.java:108)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MessageBodyParameterInjector.inject(MessageBodyParameterInjector.java:169)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.injectArguments(MethodInjectorImpl.java:136)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:159)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethod.java:257)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invoke(ResourceMethod.java:222)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invoke(ResourceMethod.java:211)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.getResponse(SynchronousDispatcher.java:542)
    ... 22 more
```

The example: https://github.com/markstein/de.mosst/tree/master/PlayareaRestEasy

Comment: You can't do that. See details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5553218/jax-rs-post-multiple-objects

Comment: Sure! I can do this. See the answer from yellow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is possible, but with carefulness.

The two parameters must be annotated with `@Form`.

```java
@Path("playarea")
public interface PlayareaRsInterface {

    @POST
    @Path("save")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public void save(@Form ComplexeObjectAleph objectAleph, @Form ComplexeObjectBeth objectBeth);

}
```

and the attributes of the two classes must have `@FormParam(...)` annotation:

```java
public class ComplexeObjectAleph {

    @FormParam("aleph")
    public String aleph;

}

public class ComplexeObjectBeth {

    @FormParam("beth")
    public String beth;

}
```

But be careful, the value of `@FormParam(...)` must be unequal, else RestEasy cannot parse the data correctly. May be that is bug of RestEasy.