# Jersey mthod argument without annotations

Tags: java, web-services, rest, annotations, jersey

In RESTful web services written using Jersey, I know I can access path parameters and query string parameters using `@PathParam` and `@QueryParam` annotaions. But in a web service written by someone else I saw a method like below.

```
@POST
@Path("/sms/receive")
@Consumes("application/json")
@Produces("application/json")
public Response smsReceive(String jsonBody) {
    //Code here...
}
```

There is no `@PathParam` or `@QueryParam`annotation before the argument jsonBody.

1. Can anybody explaing what this argument means and how to set value for it when calling this service.
2. Can I use multiple parameters without annotations?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The service above does not handle query or path parameters at all.

It `@Consumes` JSON input. That's what the method's parameter `jsonBody` is referring to.

If someone would want to instruct this service he would add a json payload to the http request which the service (in this case) receives as a simple String. The String then needs to be parsed.

Of course you can combine Path/Query Parameters with JSON Payloads.

Comment: Thanks. It makes sense. As I understood it means I can't use two arguments without annotations. For an example `public Response smsReceive(String jsonBody1, String jsonBody2)` is invalid. Am I correct?

Comment: Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5553218/jax-rs-post-multiple-objects You don't need to have several parameters. You can send mostly everything inside that json message.

Comment: Sorry I did not pay enough attention when I read it the first time. The link doe not fit exactly. You asked if you can't use two arguments without annotations. You're right. You would need to use something like `public Response smsReceive(String jsonBody, @PathParamm("foo") String foo)`