# How to use CURL to pass multiple json strings as data to a JAX-RS end point

Tags: json, curl, jax-rs

Related to this post, [JAX-RS Post multiple objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5553218/jax-rs-post-multiple-objects)

If my resource endpoint takes in `List<String>`

`@POST
    @Path("test")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public void test(List<String> jsonStrings)`

How to call this resource end point using curl (command line)

`curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://localhost:port/path/to/endpoint/test -d '{} {}'`

The above command does not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`'{} {}'` isn't valid JSON. A Java mapping terms, a `java.util.List` would be a JSON array (`[]`). So a valid input would be `-d "[ \"hello\", \"world\" ]"`. Since your list is just a of a simple type String, you don't need any curly brackets `{}`, and those signify JSON objects.

This is just simple Strings. If you want an array of object, then you would need something like `"[{\"word\" : \"hello\"},{\"word\": \"world\"}]"`, where the list `List` type would be something like

```
public class Hello {
    private String word;
    public String getWord() { return word; }
    public void setWord(String word) { this.word = word; }
}
```

So you would use `List<Hello>`. Also you need to make sure you have a JSON provider registered with the application (for POJO mapping). Some providers will auto-register, others won't If you need help with this, then please provide the JAX-RS implementation you are using, and whether or not you are using Maven.