# Entire multipart payload coming as a single FormDataParam using Jersey

Tags: java, rest, jersey, multipartform-data

I am using Jersey to build a REST service to upload a file. My method starts like this:

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
@Path("/upload")
public String upload(
    @FormDataParam("one") String one,
    @FormDataParam("two") String two,
    @FormDataParam("file") InputStream file) {
```

When I am posting a request for this resource with "one", "two" and "file" form fields, I get the entire payload, including the binary file data and multipart boundaries, in the variable "one", instead of each variable getting its respective value from the form fields.

What is going wrong here?

EDIT:
For client, I have used this HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>

    <form method="post" action="/upload"
        enctype="multipart/form-data">
        One: <input type="text" name="one" /> 
        Two: <input type="text" name="two" /> 
        File: <input type="file" name="file" />
        <input type="submit" name="Submit" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I have also tried using Postman REST client for Chrome.

**Update 1:**
As the person who asked the problem is not updating, I'll do the honors of adding data which may help in reproducing the problem -

[image: Postman Call]

[image: Java method]

[image: Debugging the above java method]

Comment: Show/explain how you are sending it from the client (whatever client that is - enough information to reproduce the problem)

Comment: Edit the question with client information.

Comment: What Jersey version are you using?

Comment: Replace `@FormDataParam("one") String one,
    @FormDataParam("two") String two,` with `@FormDataParam("one") FormDataContentDisposition one,
    @FormDataParam("two") FormDataContentDisposition two,` . Maybe this will help you out, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28670886/415-status-when-trying-to-send-formdata-in-jax-rs-jersey

Comment: I am using jersey 1.19

Comment: I'm having this same problem, with Jersey 1.19.4. The edit also exactly matches what I'm seeing

Comment: Did you have solution? I'm facing this isssue too.

Comment: This broke for me most likely after CXF 3.1 or spring 4.3 update on jersey 1.9.1. I ended up using CXF multipart annotation instead.