# Jersey REST Client : Posting MultiPart data

Tags: java, rest, jersey, multipartform-data, jersey-client

I am trying to write a Jersey client app which can post multi part form data to a Restful Jersey service. I need to post a CSV file with the data and a JSON with meta-data. I am using Jersey client 1.18.3. Here is my code (some names have been changed for company confidentiality )...

```
Client client = Client.create();
WebResource webResource = client.resource("http://localhost:8080/mariam/service/playWithDad");


    FileDataBodyPart filePart = new FileDataBodyPart("file", 
            new File("C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/input/games.csv"));

    String playWithDadMetaJson
    = "{\n"
    + "    \"sandboxIndicator\": true,\n"
    + "    \"skipBadLines\": false,\n"
    + "    \"fileSeparator\": \"COMMA\",\n"
    + "    \"blockSize\": false,\n"
    + "    \"gameUUID\": \"43a004c9-2130-4e75-8fd4-e5fccae31840\",\n"
    + "    \"useFriends\": \"false\"\n"
    + "}\n"
    + "";

    MultiPart multipartEntity = new FormDataMultiPart()
    .field("meta", playWithDadMetaJson, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE)
    .bodyPart(filePart);

    ClientResponse response = webResource.type(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_TYPE).post(multipartEntity);
```

Right now I am getting a compile error at the last line saying it cannot convert from void to ClientResponse.

I got some guidance on the RestFul service itself previously from this post..

[Java Rest Jersey : Posting multiple types of data (File and JSON)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27643558/java-rest-jersey-posting-multiple-types-of-data-file-and-json)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> "Right now I am getting a compile error at the last line saying it cannot convert from `void` to `ClientResponse`."

Look at the javadoc for [`WebResource`](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/1.18/jersey/com/sun/jersey/api/client/WebResource.html). Look at the [`post(Object)` (with Object arg)](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/1.18/jersey/com/sun/jersey/api/client/WebResource.html#post%28java.lang.Object%29). It returns void.

You need to be using the overloaded [`post(Class returnType, requestEntity)`](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/1.18/jersey/com/sun/jersey/api/client/WebResource.html#post%28java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.Object%29), which return an instance of `returnType` type.

So you should be doing something like

```
ClientResponse response = webResource
        .type(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_TYPE)
        .post(ClientResponse.class, multipartEntity);
```

Comment: Hi Peeskillet, On the server side, the service method for this client call is public PlayWithDataVO provideService(@FormDataParam("meta") String jsonMeta, @FormDataParam("data") InputStream file), but I am seeing the InputStream param is null although the json string is coming through. Any suggestions?

Comment: Never mind, I figured it out. I was missing FormDataContentDisposition which should have the same name as FormDataParam

Answer (score 12):

Follow [jersey documentation](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/media.html#multipart), they provide sample client code. Here is the snippet to post a multipart request:

```
final MultiPart multiPartEntity = new MultiPart()
        .bodyPart(new BodyPart().entity("hello"))
        .bodyPart(new BodyPart(new JaxbBean("xml"), MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_TYPE))
        .bodyPart(new BodyPart(new JaxbBean("json"), MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE));

final WebTarget target = // Create WebTarget.
final Response response = target
        .request()
        .post(Entity.entity(multiPartEntity, multiPartEntity.getMediaType()));
```

Comment: Your code (and doc link) is Jersey 2. The OP is using Jersey 1 :-)

Comment: @peeskillet Client code version does not really matter as long as POST multipart request is properly build by the client.