# How to receive 2 binary files and JSON in Jersey jax-rs?

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jax-rs

I need to build a service that can receive 2 binary files (~100k each) and some metadata, preferably in json.

I [found this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27643558/java-rest-jersey-posting-multiple-types-of-data-file-and-json), but it only seems to provide one InputStream to one of the parts. But I'd need two.. so what to do?

Comment: Just add another parameter with a different part name. What's the problem? Have you tried this?

Comment: Yes, that works. It's quite obvious now. If you want to add an answer I'll mark it as accepted.

Comment: It seems you've forgotten to accept peeskillet's answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

You have a few options

1. Simply add another parameter(s) with a different part annotation

   ```
   @POST
   @Consumes("multipart/form-data")
   public Response post(@FormDataParam("file1") InputStream file1,
                        @FormDaraParam("file2") InputStream file2) {

   }
   ```
2. The parts can have the same part name, so you could do

   ```
   @POST
   @Consumes("multipart/form-data")
   public Response post(@FormDataParam("file") List<FormDataBodyPart> files) {
       for (FormDataBodyPart file: files) {
           FormDataContentDisposition fdcd = file.getFormDataContentDisposition();
           String fileName = fdcd = getFileName();
           InputStream is = file.getValueAs(InputStream.class);
       }
   }
   ```
3. You could traverse the entire multipart body youself

   ```
   @POST
   @Consumes("multipart/form-data")
   public Response post(FormDataMultiPart mulitPart) {
       Map<String, List<FormDataBodyPart>> fields = multiPart.getFields();
   }
   ```

**See Also:**

- [Sending multiple files with Jersey: MessageBodyWriter not found for multipart/form-data](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34643414/2587435), for a complete example
- [File upload along with other object in Jersey restful web service](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27609569/2587435), for how the handle the JSON as a POJO.