# JAX-RS Consume list of json with list of files

Tags: java, jax-rs

I am interested to know if the following scenario is feasible at all:
In one request, consume a JSON/XML with a List of custom objects containing some string attributes and a list of files. Something like

```
public class MyCustomObject{
    String attr1;
    String attr2;
    List<File> files; //FileItem maybe?
//setters getters
}
```

Rest:

```
@Path("/test")
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
@POST
public Response test(List<MyCustomObject> myObjects){
//Do something with objects
}
```

Thank you for your time :)

Comment: Are you using Jersey?

Comment: Yes, Jersey is one library i can use

Comment: I dont see how this is duplicate @peeskillet. The OP on the question wants to post one file with json. I want to achieve similar functionality but consume list.

Comment: You're not going to be able to do this exactly the way you want without custom deserialization.

Comment: Now that comment makes more sense. It is not duplicate. Ok, seems custom deserialization is the way to go.

Comment: You might want to just get the FormDataMultiPart, and traverse the data yourself. That would be easier than custom deserizialization.

Comment: I kind of looking to learn, I could also do multiple posts such as you have answered in the other question, but I am gonna go the tough way. If you have some suggestions on some docs i'd be grateful

Comment: You can have a look at [this](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/media.html#d0e9409), [this](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/2.22.1/jersey/index.html?org/glassfish/jersey/media/multipart/FormDataMultiPart.html) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34646196/2587435)