# ClientHandlerException: MIME media type, multipart/form-data, was not found

Tags: java, rest, file-upload, multipart, jersey-client

I am using Jersey client to hit a Spring MVC REST Controller for image uploading functionality. I am getting the following exception:

```
com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: A message body writer for Java type, class org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartFile, and MIME media type, multipart/form-data, was not found
```

My Controller Method to POST the Image:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/file/upload", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String fileUpload(@RequestParam("fileUpload") MultipartFile file, 
Model model, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
{
try
{   
    ClientConfig config = new DefaultClientConfig();
    com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client client = com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.create(config);
    WebResource webResource = client.resource("/save-image");

    ClientResponse responseMsg = webResource
            .type(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
            .post(ClientResponse.class, file);          
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    logger.error("Exception in fileUpload()", e);
    return "error";
}
return "success";
}
```

My REST Controller method get the post data:

```
@ResponseBody
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
@RequestMapping(value = "/save-image", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String saveImage(@FormDataParam("file") MultipartFile file, ModelMap 
model)
{
    //Code to save the image
}
```

Is there a solution to this exception. I have tried according to the following stack solutions but I am still getting the same exception.

[Jersey client exception: A message body writer was not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15585074/jersey-client-exception-a-message-body-writer-was-not-found)

[Sending multiple files with Jersey: MessageBodyWriter not found for multipart/form-data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34643414/sending-multiple-files-with-jersey-messagebodywriter-not-found-for-multipart-fo)

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the dependencies for multipart?

```
<!-- Jersey client support  -->
      <dependency>
       <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
       <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
       <version>1.9</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
       <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
       <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
       <version>1.9</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-multipart</artifactId>
        <version>1.9</version>
    </dependency>

      <dependency>
       <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
       <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
       <version>1.3.2</version>
      </dependency>

    <!-- Apache Commons FileUpload -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: I have these dependencies added to my pom.xml