# Trouble in posting data as form data in Angular JS to Java REST web-service

Tags: java, angularjs, http-post, jax-rs

I am trying to create a web service in `Java` that accepts two lists as `FormData` parameter.

I have used the Angualr JS `http` service as mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11442632/how-can-i-post-data-as-form-data-instead-of-a-request-payload/11443066#11443066).

```
var queryRequest = $http({
    method:'POST',
    url:'services/test/testPath',
    data:$.param({"listA":myList1,"listB":myList2}),
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8'}
});
```

My object `myList1`

```
var myList1=[];
var obj={};
obj["val1"]=1
obj["val2"]=2
myList1.push(obj);
```

My object `myList2`

```
var myList2=[];

var obj={};
obj["val11"]=3
obj["val12"]=4
myList2.push(obj);

var obj={};
obj["val11"]=5
obj["val12"]=6
myList2.push(obj);
```

I am using `javax.ws.rs.*` for the rest service

And my Java server endpoint, which accepts the data, is as-

```
@Path("testPath")
@POST
@Consumes("application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8")
@Produces("application/json")
public DataDTO addIssuancesForFP(@FormParam("listA") List<TypeA> list1, @FormParam("listB") List<TypeB> list2) {

    System.out.println("Service is called correctly");
    return service.getDTO(list1,list2);
}
```

My classe 'TypeA'

```
 private Integer val1;
 private Integer val2;
 //getters and setters, and default constructor
```

My classe 'TypeB'

```
 private Integer val11;
 private Integer val12;
 //getters and setters, and default constructor
```

Endpoint is hitting correctly, but I am getting `null` in both the list.  The request structure is:

> Request Type

```
    Accept:application/json, text/plain, */*
    Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8
```

> Form Data

```
    listA[0][val1]:1
    listA[0][val2]:2

    listB[0][val11]:3
    listB[0][val12]:4
    listB[1][val11]:5
    listB[1][val12]:6
```

It seems to be correct, I think mistake is in server part. How to resolve this?

Thanks

**Note:** This is just the mock data, which is in exact same format

Comment: form data or from data??

Comment: @roxid changed to `form data`

Comment: So are `[val1]`, etc. properties on Javascript objects? Is that how the data is actually sent out, i.e `listA[0][val1]=value1`? Can you show the actual Javascript objects of `myList1` and `myList2`. Also can show the `TypeA` and `TypeB` classes.

Comment: Ok I will check it out right now

Comment: I didn't see your complete update. It shows usable objects I think. I just wanted to look a the actual request and see how the data is being sent

Comment: @peeskillet: This is actual mock data, I just tested, and upadetd

Comment: Yeah I don't think this format is going to work. I have an alternate solution. Will post in a bit. Might take a minute

Comment: @peeskillet: I acheived it by wrapping these two list in one class, and pass the object of that class

Comment: Yeah that would work also :-), but not with the media type you are trying to use, did it?. I'm sure you changed it to JSON?

Comment: Yes, I changed to JSON media type, and accepting as `@RequestBody`

Comment: `@RequestBody`? That's a Spring annotation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah so I don't think using form encoded data is going to work. The reason is that it is mainly for key value pairs, in the form

```
key1=value7&key2=value2&key3=value3...
```

What you are doing is using only two keys, `listA` and `listB`. So imagine what the values would need to look like, to send the entire list. It isn't pretty. For complex data, it is more viable to send the data in a format like JSON. The problem with this for your particular use case  is that there are two unrelated objects (or arrays) to needs to send. For this, a solution would be to use multipart. You're in luck, because I just posted a [late answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29307655/2587435) yesterday, on exactly how this can be handled with Angular.

I won't go through an explanation here about the code. Everything is explained in that link. Please read through it, as you go through this answer. I will be using Jersey as may JAX-RS implementation (as does the example in the link - but it also offers other alternative implementations)

Resource

```
import java.util.List;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.FormDataParam;

@Path("/form")
public class FormResource {

    @POST
    @Consumes("multipart/form-data")
    @Produces("text/plain")
    public String addIssuancesForFP(@FormDataParam("listA") List<TypeA> list1, 
                                     @FormDataParam("listB") List<TypeB> list2) {

        StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
        for(TypeA a: list1) {
            response.append(a.toString()).append("; ");
        }

        for (TypeB b: list2) {
            response.append(b.toString()).append("; ");
        }

        System.out.println("Service is called correctly");
        return response.toString();
    }
}
```

Angular

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="formApp">
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <script src="js/libs/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="js/libs/angular.js/angular.js"></script>
        <script>
            angular.module("formApp", [])
            .controller("defaultCtrl", function($scope, $http) {
                $scope.sendData = function() {
                    var myList1 = [];
                    var obj = {};
                    obj["val1"] = "value1";
                    obj["val2"] = "value2";
                    myList1.push(obj);

                    var myList2 = [];

                    var obj = {};
                    obj["val11"] = "value11";
                    obj["val12"] = "value12";
                    myList2.push(obj);

                    var obj = {};
                    obj["val11"] = "value211";
                    obj["val12"] = "value212";
                    myList2.push(obj);

                    var list1 = JSON.stringify(myList1);
                    var list2 = JSON.stringify(myList2);

                    var boundary = Math.random().toString().substr(2);
                    var header = "multipart/form-data; charset=utf-8; boundary=" + boundary;

                    $http({
                        url: "/api/form",
                        headers: {"Content-Type": header},
                        data: createRequest(list1, list2, boundary),
                        method: "POST"
                    }).then(function(response) {
                        $scope.result = response.data;
                    });

                    function createRequest(list1, list2, boundary) {
                        var multipart = "";
                        multipart += "--" + boundary
                            + "\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=listA"
                            + "\r\nContent-type: application/json"
                            + "\r\n\r\n" + list1 + "\r\n";
                        multipart += "--" + boundary
                            + "\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=listB"
                            + "\r\nContent-type: application/json"
                            + "\r\n\r\n" + list2 + "\r\n";
                            multipart += "--" + boundary + "--\r\n";
                        return multipart;
                    }
                };
             });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div ng-controller="defaultCtrl">
            <button ng-click="sendData()">Send</button>
            <p>{{result}}
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Result

```
TypeA{val1=value1, val2=value2}; 
TypeB{val1=value11, val2=value12}; 
TypeB{val1=value211, val2=value212};
```

Which is expected, as I just built a string from the `toString()` methods, which I implemented in the `TypeA` and `TypeB` classes.

```
public class TypeA {
    public String val1;
    public String val2;
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "TypeA{" + "val1=" + val1 + ", val2=" + val2 + '}';
    }
}

public class TypeB {
    public String val11;
    public String val12;
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "TypeB{" + "val1=" + val11 + ", val2=" + val12 + '}';
    } 
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried this also, but I was getting something like `could not found boundary of media error`, What does this `boundary` is for?

Comment: It 's part of the [multipart](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.2) specification. Most likely you did not send the request out correctly, maybe allowing the browser to create the request. Even if you set the content type to false/undefined, using `FormData` as proposed in some of [these answers](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5392344/2587435), the data would still be sent out as plain text, and you would still need to parse it on the server side. With the JSON approach, you let the framework parse it. In the solution above, we are created the request body ourselves

Comment: And also, I do not have `@FormDataParam` annotation, that you have imported from `org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.FormDataParam;` and   I was using `javax.ws.rs.FormParam;`. Is there any alternative for this in Spring web. I am also using this `org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody`

Comment: Are you using Jersey? If so, go to the link, and it will have the Maven dependency you need to add. Then you need to register the feature also. The link shows Java configuration of the feature. If you are using web.xml, then you can set an init param for the jersey servlet `jersey.config.server.provider.classnames` - value - `org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.MultiPartFeature`

Comment: I am not using `Jersey`, I am using `javax.ws.rs` APIs, and also Spring. For example `RequestBody` was Spring annotation and `QueryParam` was `javax` annotation. `FormDataParam` is not there. How can I add

Comment: `javax.ws.rs` does nothing. It is a specification API jar. There needs to be an implementation of it. If you're using only that jar, then you are using a Java ee server which has the implementation. Which server are you using?

Comment: Also I don't know how you are integrating Spring with JAX-RS without an implementation. You sure you aren't using something like CXF (which is a JAX-RS implementation)?

Comment: I am using `CXFUtils`. In my `web.xml`, I have a servlet `<servlet>
   <servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
   <servlet-class>org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet</servlet-class>
 </servlet>`

Is that what you are asking? I have just started using  these, so not of much idea.. learning

Comment: Do you know what version of CXF you are using? See if there's a `@Multipart` annotation.

Comment: See [here](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-rs-multiparts.html) for general support with multipart for CXF, and an example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28483262/2587435)

Comment: Its CXFUtils version 2.3, I just checked my `ivy`, and other one is `CXF Bundle jar` 2.2.6.. And yes `@Multipart` is there `org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.ext.multipart.Multipart`