# How to send the list of entities from the jersey service endpoint?

Tags: java, web-services, jersey

I am sending the list of entities from the jersey server. At client side i am trying to get those list of entities. But it is giving unmarshal excepiton.

Why it is adding 's' at the end of elementname i.e "emps" instead of "emp".

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Emp{
...
}

Server side code:
@POST
    @Path("/getallemps")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    public List<Emp> getAllEmployees2(@Context HttpServletRequest request, @Context HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException{
        List<Emp> el = new ArrayList<Emp>();
....
return el;
}

client side code:
public void testGetAllEmployees(){
        String res = null;
        ClientConfig config = new DefaultClientConfig();
        Client client = Client.create(config);
        WebResource resource = client.resource(uri);
...
ClientResponse response = resource.type(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML).post(ClientResponse.class);
        List<Emp> li = response.getEntity(new GenericType<List<Emp>>(Emp.class));
}

Exception is:
....unmarshalexception unexpected element(url="" local="emps") expected element {}emp
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `response.getEntity(new GenericType<List<Emp>>(Emp.class));`

use `response.getEntity(new GenericType<List<Emp>>(){});`

Not quite sure why the former does not work, but I tested with the latter and it works fine.

Comment: How to unmarshal the custom exception at client side http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29897075/how-to-marshal-and-unmarshal-the-custom-exception