# How to upload binary file(Photos etc ) with Meta Data using REST

Tags: rest, jersey, media-type

One way of doing is to convert the binary data to Base64 and send it along with meta data as `MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON`.

The problem with this is client has to convert the binary data into Base64 before sending.

I also tried sending using `MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM` format through REST. This works fine for binary data only.

One option is to send meta data in headers while using `MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM`.

Is there any better way?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `multipart/form-data`. This is what it's meant for. Not sure which Jersey version you are using, but here is the link for the Jersey 2.x documentation for [Multipart support](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/media.html#multipart). Here's for [1.x](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/1.18/user-guide.html#d4e1840) (not really much information). You will need to do some searching for using multipart with Javascript clients (there is a bunch of information out there)

- Here is a good [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27614403/2587435) of using Jersey 2.x with both the server side and the client API.
- Here is [an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29630763/2587435) with Jersey 1.x. You can see the API it not much different.

Comment: Thanks @peeskillet.  One question : If I want to pass name of parts in multipart/mixed , How can I do it ?   Similar to something like  http://pastebin.com/bLdsXNhv but using multipart/mixed

Comment: Not sure. It seems to be form-data specific. I don't see anything in the API nor in the [RFC](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/7_2_Multipart.html)

Comment: I will stick to form-data. Any suggestion for getting Binary stream of data along with Metadata

Comment: I thought that's what the links I provided do... What exactly is the problem you are facing in doing this?

Comment: Uploads worked fine. Now, I want to download the file which was upload using upload operation along with its metadata. Any suggestions ?