# Jersey Grizzly Rest How to extract "form-data" parameters

Tags: rest, post, jersey, multipartform-data, grizzly

Consider following function:

```
@POST
    @Path("/handle_response")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public ResponseJsonBean handle(@FormParam("first") Integer first, @FormParam("second") Integer second) 
    {
        ////// bla bla
    }
```

The above function is called when I make a POST x-www-form-urlencoded request. But the function is not called when I make POST form data request. Why it is not called in the latter case? and how can I make such function which works for latter request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and `multipart/form-data` are complete different types and formats. The correct provider to read the request is discovered through the type sent.

For multipart support, you should add the Jersey multipart dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>
    <version>${jersey2.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Then in your resource method do something like

```
@POST
@Path("/upload")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes({MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA})
public Response uploadFile(
        @FormDataParam("file") InputStream fileInputStream,
        @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition cdh) throws Exception{
}
```

**See Also:**

- [An example with the client side also](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27614403/2587435)
- [Jersey Multipart Documentation](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/media.html#multipart)
- [In case you are using Jersey 1.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29628097/how-to-submit-multiple-entities-to-the-post-method-from-jersey-client-program/29630763#29630763)

Comment: Are multipart/form-data and form-data alone, same things?

Comment: There's no such thing (or at least media type) as form-data

Comment: Actually I have to integrate my rest web service with a developer who is POSTing simple parameters using form-data. There is no file to upload.

Comment: Why did you tag your question `multipartform-data` then. There is no such media type as `form-data` why don't you figure out the exact media type you need, then maybe I can answer your question better

Comment: Also multipart/form-data doesn't need to be file. It can be simple text if you want. But I  don't see why you would want to use multipart for simple text, when form-urlencoded is just fine. See [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4) to see the difference between the two and when they should be used

Comment: please also tell how to extract string parameters from multiparr form-data

Comment: Did you try to simply put a String as a parameter?