# Mapping JSON properties to method parameters with Jackson (JAX-RS)

Tags: java, json, jackson, jax-rs, jackson2

I'm using Jackson 2 on a JAX-RS project, and I have a method that expects a JSON with this structure:

```
{
    "actor": { "name": "Joe" },
    "movie": { "title": "The Movie" }
}
```

I was able to map this to an object using a custom wrapper class:

```
class MyInput {
    Actor actor;
    Movie movie;
}

// resource method signature:
public Response query(MyInput input);
```

Is it possible to avoid using the custom class, and have Jackson map the `actor` and `movie` properties directly to parameters?

I would then use a method like this:

```
public Response query(Actor actor, Movie movie);
```

Comment: No it's not possible (at least not without hacking and overriding the default behavior)... huge emphasis on _hacking_

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5553218/jax-rs-post-multiple-objects) may provide you with a more comprehensive answer.